# Restoring Old VBA On Error

Tags: vba, onerror

Let's say you have On Error Defined in  your main sub.

```
Sub Main()

   On Error Goto CatchAll
   '... Some code... goes here
   Call XYZ



CatchAll:
   Msgbox "An Unexpected Error Occurred"
   End
End Sub
```

Within Main sub, you have a call to routine XYZ.
Let's say that Sub XYZ is like this:

```
Sub XYZ()
   'If unexpected error happens here, control will be shifted to sub Main, Label CatchAll

   On Error Goto Errorz

   'If unexpected error happens here, control will be shifted to same sub, Label Errorz...

Errorz:
        Msgbox "You have crashed inside XYZ"
        End

End Sub
```

Note the comments entered in sub XYZ.
Namely, where the control shifts after a program crash is experienced is based on the last "On Error Goto" statement.

Is there a way, in VBA, to restore the old On Error Goto?

In other words, within Sub XYZ, I have some code:

```
Sub XYZ()
   On Error Goto Errorz:

   'Some Code

   On Error Goto <Old Error Trapping Method>
   'Here I desire to go back to Main CatchAll: label.  Is there a way to do that?

End Sub
```

Note the last comment in the code above.  I want to be able to redefine On Error to restore the last behavior of On error before I defined the new behavior (Last Behavior:  Goto Main.CatchAll label,   New behavior, Goto XYZ.Errorz label).  I want to be able to, at this point in the code, say, On error Go to Main.CatchAll.

Is there some way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in XYZ()

```
On Error Goto 0
```

should clear the current procedure's (i.e. XYZ()'s) error handler and in your example pass control of error handling to the error handler in Main().

Comment: so simple... I didn't know it would pop back up to parent sub.  thx.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Short of outright [clearing local error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48101934/1188513), you can conditionally *rethrow* the error in the handler:

```
Errorz:
    With Err
        If .Number = SomeSpecificLocalError Then
            ' mitigate error
            Resume Next
        Else
            ' rethrow
            .Raise .Number
        End If
    End With
```

That way you preserve the original error message (optionally you could specify a `source` and a more descriptive `message` for the "catch-all" handler to see) and "bubble" errors up the call stack.

Let's illustrate the difference with another language:

```
try
{
    // do stuff
}
catch
{
    // handle error
}

// do more stuff
```

The above snippet is essentially what `On Error GoTo 0` does: whatever happens in `do more stuff`, if an error is thrown, the caller will need to handle it.

Now compare to:

```
try
{
    // do stuff
    // do more stuff
}
catch(InvalidOperationException e)
{
    // handle invalid operation
}
catch(FileNotFoundException)
{
    throw;
}
catch(Exception)
{
    // handle any other exception
}
```

Here the local scope will handle an `InvalidOperationException`, but a `FileNotFoundException` will be explicitly *re-thrown* for the calling code to handle, while any other exception will be handled locally.

Both methods have pros and cons, I'm just leaving this here for posterity: you *can* re-throw a runtime error in VBA if you want to.

That said, needing multiple error-handling strategies inside a single procedure is a code smell IMO: your procedure might be responsible for too many things, split it up.

Comment: FWIW, the original error message is preserved automatically if an `On Error GoTo 0` in `XYZ` has forced the error to be handled in `Main`'s `CatchAll` handler.

Comment: Can't you on error exit sub to go back to main and go into the error handling?  (perhaps a new eror handler for this but may not have the result you want) No error then proceed into sub and use subs error handler?  You want to return to main with an error, I suppose you are asking if you encounter one error handler does it supercede the previous error handler.

Comment: @YowE3K I didn't mean to imply otherwise. What I meant was that `Err.Raise Err.Number` is effectively rethrowing the very same error, including the original message and source. Edited to clarify.

Comment: @Wookies-Will-Code of course you can. I've edited to clarify, hope it helps.

Comment: The edit to handle some errors and rethrow other errors clears up my misunderstanding of what you were trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

This kicks back out to main easily enough and into your error handler.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

On Error GoTo CatchAll

Call XYZ

Exit Sub

CatchAll:
MsgBox "This is Catchall Error Handling"
End Sub

Private Sub XYZ()

'This will purposely throw an error
'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet55").Range("A1").Value = 10

On Error GoTo 0
'This will purposely throw an error
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet66").Range("A1").Value = 10

MsgBox "You made it to here? Wow!"

End Sub
```

[image]

If you must have an in sub error handler the answer from below is right when using rethrow, also works, man you guys are smart:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

On Error GoTo CatchAll

Call XYZ

Exit Sub

CatchAll:
MsgBox "This is Catchall Error Handling"
End Sub

Private Sub XYZ()

'This will purposely throw an error
'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet55").Range("A1").Value = 10

On Error GoTo Err_XYZ
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet66").Range("A1").Value = 10

MsgBox "You made it to here? Wow!"

Exit Sub

Err_XYZ:
With Err
.Raise .Number
End With
End Sub
```

Cheers, -WWC

Comment: I think you guys already have it, Goto 0 from a number of people, @S Meaden, *YowE3k and *Mat's Mug.  If you want more control and bubbling then there are other ways, but his simply kicks out to the caller to handle it. - WWC

Comment: Both of those answers above are correct depending on what you want, I tested them both.  Great job guys!